# Where can i find collection of various common File Extension structure?

Tags: c++, file-io

Suppose i want to fstream some image file like jpeg, i'd need to know its internal structure, and how it is stored. Therefore, i just want to know if there exist some website that collect information on structure of each file extension? There's only website such as filext.com that tell us about what kind of file it is. I just want to know if there exists websites or documents that generally tell me all common file extension's structure.

PS: if there isn't one, then i'll have to lookup each file extensions' documentation...

Comment: You might want to take a look at the implementation of the `file` utility in linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.wotsit.org/ Has descriptions for many file formats.

You will have a hard time implementing parsers for "all common file extensions" though. You are probably going to have better success using libraries, or depending what you are trying to do, using OS-specific file info functions. Maybe even supporting an existing plugin format like Windows Explorer.

Comment: One for each file format you want to support (e.g. libpng for .png files) I think you'll get better help if you specify what your goal is - why do you need to do this?

Comment: It's my habit to get thing organized beforehand, so when i plan to use them, i won't need to waste my time finding. It is more like self-organized references.